# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ECoffeeShopJSF: Compilation failure

Tags: jsf, deployment, compiler-errors

I had completed JSF project and I want to deploy on Azure. I using GitHub action (connected with Azure) to build and deploy it. But, it appear this error when build `pom.xml`.

This is error image:

[image: error screenshot]

This is my `pom.xml`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>ECoffeeShopJSF</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <name>ECoffeeShopJSF</name>
            <properties>
                <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            </properties>       
            <build>
                <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                    <silent>true</silent>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                            <version>7.0</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build> 
        </project>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. - Its better giving errormessages as text than as image!

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question